# Find the sub-paths of files with specific externsion in python

Tags: python

I am trying to locate all my files with externsion mp4 in a folder(and subfolder) and copy them in another dir. I manage to find all files with the extension mp4 however I didnt manage to keep the dir of those files. My code is the following:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

path = "videos/"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
       if name.endswith((".mp4", ".mp4")):
          print(name)
          # copyfile(src, dst)
```

I want to find the path of the name (corresponding to my vids). How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.join()`

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

path = "videos/"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
       if name.endswith((".mp4", ".mp4")):
          print(os.path.join(root, name))
          # copyfile(src, dst)
```

Although it is considered better to use absolute paths but you can use [os.path.relpath](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.relpath) if you want relative path. From the `os.path.relpath` documentation

> os.path.relpath(path[, start])
>
> Return a relative filepath to path either from the current directory or from an optional start directory. This is a path computation: the filesystem is not accessed to confirm the existence or nature of path or start.
>
> start defaults to os.curdir.
>
> Availability: Windows, Unix.
>
> New in version 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `glob`:

```
import glob, shutil
for file in glob.iglob('/foo/*.mp4'): 
    shutil.copy2(file, '/bar/{0}'.format(file))
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation on os.walk:

> dirpath is a string, the path to the directory. dirnames is a list of the names of the subdirectories in dirpath (excluding '.' and '..'). filenames is a list of the names of the non-directory files in dirpath. Note that the names in the lists contain no path components. To get a full path (which begins with top) to a file or directory in dirpath, do os.path.join(dirpath, name).

So your code should look like this:

```
import os
from shutil import copyfile

path = "videos/"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for name in files:
       if name.endswith((".mp4", ".mp4")):
          print(name)
          src = os.path.join(root, name)
          copyfile(src, dst)
```